# _this2.onPressed is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

When I press TouchableOpacity inside the renderItem method I get an error "_this2.onPressed is not a function".

I found a documentation about passing functions to component (link is given below): 
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

I have tried these solutions but it didn't work.
How do I fix this problem? I am new to React Native.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, FlatList,View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPosts,likePost} from '../../actions'
import {Card} from '../Card';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'


class PostScreen2 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.onPressed = this.onPressed.bind(this)
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProp, nextState){
        console.log("Should component update")
        return true
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const {id} = this.props
        console.log("ID'miz: ", id)
        this.props.fetchPosts(id)
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("Component did update.")
    }

    onPressed(postID){
        this.props.likePost(postID,this.props.id)
    }

    renderItem({item}){
        return(
            <Card>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'column',position:'absolute', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                    <View style={styles.topWrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
                            <Image source={require('../../images/cat.png')}></Image>
                        </View>
                    <View style={styles.infoWrapper}>
                        <Text style={styles.nameWrapper}>{item.author_name}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>{item.date}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{item.content}</Text>
                </View>
                    <View styles={styles.likeWrapper}>
                        <Text style={{marginLeft:10, fontSize:18, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.likes} likes</Text>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressed(item.id)}}>
                        <Icon style={{marginLeft:10}} size={25} name='star-o' />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Card>         
        )        
    }

    render() {
        const {posts} = this.props
        return (
            <FlatList
            data={posts}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    var posts = []
    for (var property in state.posts.data) {
      posts = state.posts.data[property]
    }

    return {
        posts,
        id: state.id
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    titleWrapper:{
        fontSize: 16,
        color: 'black'
    },
    authorWrapper: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: 'gray'
    },
    descriptionWrapper: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        fontSize: 13,
        color: 'gray'
    },
    imageWrapper: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginTop: 10
    },
    nameWrapper: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 20
    },
    infoWrapper:{
      marginLeft: 10,
      marginTop: 10
    },
    topWrapper:{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    contentWrapper: {
      marginLeft: 10,
      marginRight: 10,
    },
    likeWrapper: {
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts,likePost})(PostScreen2);
```

Comment: change the renderItem function like arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the render method to the following?

```
    ...
    renderItem =({item}) => {
            return(
                <Card>
                    ...
                    ...
                </Card>         
            )        
    }
    ...
```

I think you have to bind the render method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you explain it little more? :) Why did I do this?

Comment: In react native, we need to bind function. Then only we can get the instance of 'this'. If we not bind functions we don't get the class 'this' object. We can bind functions in different ways. please refer https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're new to javascript too. The way you declared(or tried to declare) `onPressed` and the `renderItem` function is not right. Use this code instead inside your class:

```
onPressed = (postID) => {
  this.props.likePost(postID,this.props.id)
}
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return(
        <Card>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',position:'absolute', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                <View style={styles.topWrapper}>
                    <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
                        <Image source={require('../../images/cat.png')}></Image>
                    </View>
                <View style={styles.infoWrapper}>
                    <Text style={styles.nameWrapper}>{item.author_name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>{item.date}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{item.content}</Text>
            </View>
                <View styles={styles.likeWrapper}>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft:10, fontSize:18, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.likes} likes</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressed(item.id)}}>
                    <Icon style={{marginLeft:10}} size={25} name='star-o' />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Card>         
    )        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer but, just to elaborate a bit more.

In order to solve this problem you have to understand how you use callbacks in Javascript and what is the context(this).

React invokes the callback methods in another context, and you have two options.

- Bind your function with this;
- Use arrow functions that share the context (this). So, you don´t need to bind them with your context.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  onPress() {
    // Not your this so you do not have access to your class
    // In order to bind this function you can put ``this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)` on class constructor.
  }

  arrowOnPress = () => {
    // Your class this
    this.onPress();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={this.onPress} title="I am not binded" />
        <Button onPress={this.arrowOnPress} title="I am binded" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps